# Javascript equivalent to php's urldecode()

Tags: javascript, urldecode

I wrote a custom xml parser and its locking up on special characters. So naturally I urlencoded them into my database.

I can't seem to find an equivalent to php's `urldecode()`.

Are there any extentions for [jquery](http://jquery.com) or javascript that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You could use [the `decodeURIComponent` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/decodeURIComponent) to convert the %xx into characters. However, to convert `+` into spaces you need to replace them in an extra step.

```
function urldecode(url) {
  return decodeURIComponent(url.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I modified it slightly to take any variable:  

    `function urldecode(str) { 
      if (typeof str != "string") { 
        return str; 
      } 
      return decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\+/g, ' ')); 
    }`

Comment: note this will not work for non-standard utf8 characters. E.g. `'%F7'`. php's urldecode will still store the correct bytes `0xF7` whereas `decodeURIComponent` will throw an error

Answer (score 14):

Check out this one

```
function urldecode (str) {
  return decodeURIComponent((str + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}
```

Comment: While a nice addition to the already suggested answers, you probably should include some suggestion of why it would be better / what the trade off is against the other options listed here.

Comment: From my understanding this will turn `+` into `%20`, which is the encoded value of a space (which then gets decoded by decodeURIComponent).  So theoretically this will do the same as the accepted answer, just a different way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the `decodeURI` function.

Comment: Not entirely (see Kenny's answer).