# Angular - '==' is not included as URL parameter

Tags: angular, http, get, request

I have a request of this format:

```
http://localhost:2534/members/all/33/AlzdpoiasklnlasEE==
```

but, when I send a request to my API Endpoint, the `==` is always missing.

So, the parameter value would be just `AlzdpoiasklnlasEE`.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: "=" is a reserved character in/for URLs, you have to encode them (AlzdpoiasklnlasEE%3D%3D) and then decode it on the server side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble in passing "=" (equal) symbol in subsequent request - Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994959/trouble-in-passing-equal-symbol-in-subsequent-request-jmeter) For the fix: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6544564/215552

Answer (score 0):

= is a reserved character.

Additional info here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent
- https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send it as part of URL, this has to be encoded using `encodeURIComponent` since it is a reserved character. EX:

```
encodeURIComponent('AlzdpoiasklnlasEE==') // will return "AlzdpoiasklnlasEE%3D%3D"
```

> URLs do not allow many special characters, like spaces or slashes.
> However these special characters are part of life, so URL is needed.

You can use `decodeURIComponent` at server to reverse a string's URL encoding and and get normal text value.

Characters that are [reserved](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) within a query component and/or have special meaning within a URI/URL:

```
 reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
```

The "reserved" syntax class above refers to those characters that are allowed within a URI, but which may not be allowed within a particular component of the generic URI syntax. C**haracters in the "reserved" set are not reserved in all contexts.** The hostname, for example, can contain an optional username so it could be something like `ftp://user@hostname/` where the '@' character has special meaning.